# Passing csv files as arguments to a function

Tags: python, function, file, csv

```
  infile = open('abc.csv', "r")

  infile1 = open('xyz.csv', "r") 

  infile2 = open('pqr.csv', "r")
```

I am trying to read 3 csv files into infile, infile1, infile2. After that i have to pass them to a function. The problem is when i am trying to pass directly in, in1, in2 as arguments its showing

> **ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10:**

```
convert_to(infile, infile1, infile2)

def convert_to(..,..,..)
```

How can i pass in, in1, in2 as arguments to the function definition and call? Is this the right way then why it is showing this error. Is there any other better and efficient way to do this?

Comment: Show some code. [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: replace in = open('abc.csv', "r") to in_0 = open('abc.csv', "r")

Comment: and if you show us the code, we can help you in better way.

Comment: You’re opening the file in read mode, but not reading the contents of the csv. Once you do infile = open(...) you should read it infile_contents = infile.read() and then finally infile.close()

Comment: post the relevant code and the full traceback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just an suggestion, why don't you use `pandas`.

In case of `pandas` it is very easy to pass them as object to functions and do whatever you want to do with it.

```
import pandas as pd
in1 = pd.read_csv('path/to/file1.csv')
in2 = pd.read_csv('path/to/file2.csv')
in3 = pd.read_csv('path/to/file3.csv')

def convert_to(*args):
    for df in args:
        print "hi"

convert_to(in1,in2,in3)
```

Let me know if pandas works for you.

## Another Solution:

in `convert_to` are you trying to convert any value to `integer`. It might be an issue in your case. Converting `string` into `integer` will throw the error that you have mentioned at the top. 
here is an example:

```
print int('56.0000')
print float('56.0000')
```

you can observe,

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '56.0000000'
```

for first case and for the second case,

```
56.0
```

I think that is the issue you are having.

Comment: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '44.37248774328121'.. how to fix this

Comment: do `float('44.37248774328121')` then if really want to convert it into integer then do `int` of that number

Comment: i need to convert to int. I will try this!

Answer (score 1):

First, you can't use *in* as a variable name since it's a reserved word in python:

```
import csv

file1 = open("abc.csv", "r")
file2 = open("xyz.csv", "r")
file3 = open("pqr.csv", "r")

def convert_to(a, b, c):
    ...

convert_to(file1, file2, file3)
```

Also, that's not the way I would do it since I would like to make sure the file is closed after it has been used. See [this](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/). I would create a function that accepts the filenames as arguments and then process the files inside the function:

```
import csv

filename1 = "abc.csv"
filename2 = "xyz.csv"
filename3 = "pqr.csv"

def convert_to(a, b, c):
    with open(a, "r") as file1:
        pass # do something with file abc.csv
    with open(b, "r") as file1:
        pass # do something with file xyz.csv
    with open(c, "r") as file1:
        pass # do something with file pqr.csv

convert_to(filename1, filename2, filename3)
```

Answer (score 0):

"in" is a keyword. You should change that variable name.

Not just the variable name... you need to change the parameters also.

i did it, and it worked fine for me.

```
import csv

in1 = open('abc.csv', "r")

in2 = open('xyz.csv', "r")

in3 = open('pqr.csv', "r")

def convert_to(in1, in2, in3):
    return 'hi'

print(convert_to(in1,in2,in3))
```

Comment: I edited my post to reflect the changes. Try that, and let me know what you think.

Answer (score 0):

```
  import csv
  csv_files = ['abc.csv','xyz.csv','abcd.csv']  
  def convert_to(files):
      for file in files:
          with open(file,'r') as f:
              # Do something
```

You can pass the list of files to a function then made the changes/covert them as you wish.

Comment: if i try to pass multiple files like ['abc1.csv','xyz1.csv','abcd1.csv','abc2.csv','xyz2.csv','abcd2.csv'] and i have to read ['abc1.csv','xyz1.csv','abcd1.csv'] in 1st pass to the function and ['abc2.csv','xyz2.csv','abcd2.csv'] in 2nd pass... i can change open as open("abc_%s.csv" % i, "r")  but what about the for loop.. any suggestions for multiple files

Comment: Yes, you can pass them as you wish 

but you need to split the list and pass them to the function and do your computations. 

files = ['abc.csv','abcd.csv','xyz.csv']
1st call: convert_to(files[:2]) 
2nd call: convert_to(files[2:])

my suggestion is to use python pandas to work on CSV and data computations stuff it has got numerous functionalities. If u can able to tell us exact requirement in simple words it'd be great help in both ways. Thanks